# How exactly is memory overwritten

Tags: memory

When learning about memory corruption and exploits I found it hard to understand how exactly memory is overwritten in the low down sense.

Say you have two list variables each with 8 bytes of memory one called **'BUFFERONE'** and the other **'BUFFERTWO'** both initialized in order of left to right.

I am under the understanding that memory is most commonly stored in a way that goes from high to low addresses, so in memory **'BUFFERONE'** would be at a higher address then **'BUFFERTWO'**.

Say the following function is ran with the argument of **'1234567890'**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  char BUFFERONE[8], BUFFERTWO[8];
  strcpy(BUFFERTWO, argv[1]);
  
  printf("BUFFERTWO HAS THE VALUE %s", BUFFERTWO);
  printf("BUFFERONE HAS THE VALUE %s", BUFFERONE);
  
  return 1;
}
```

With no Stack or Memory Protections such as ASLR, writing **'1234567890'** into **'BUFFERTWO'** will overwrite **'90'** into **'BUFFERONE'**.

Is this because memory is stored in little-endian. So in order to append to the end of a string stored in memory you have to overwrite memory towards higher address. Therefore overwriting into the higher addressed variable **'BUFFERONE'**

Am I correct in my thinking or am I completely off? Any Help to understand would be greatly appreciated